# Download and rename a file via url with PHP

Tags: php, download

I have this URL

> www1.intranet.com/reportingtool.asp?settings=var&export = ok

There I can download a report. The file-name of the report includes a timestamp. e.g. **123981098298.xls** and varies everytime I download it.

I want to have a script with this functions:

```
<?php
//Download the File

//rename it to **report.xls**

//save it to a specified place
?>
```

I don't have any idea after searching stackoverflow and googling on this topic :(

Is this generally possible?

Comment: This is absolutely possible. However SO is NOT a place to have others do YOUR work, sorry. This place is to get help when you are stuck with a problem with your own implementation. So: learn the most basic things about php first, solve this really easy task and then, if you really run into a problem with this, then ask here.

Comment: Does the source website require authentication before allowing access to the report? If so, what type? When you say "save to a specified place", what kind of place would that be? On the server where PHP runs? On the client (if your script is accessed via an URL)? How is the script going to be accessed anyway?

Comment: Ok @arkascha this is good news that it is possible! Thanks :)

Comment: @Jon : It doesn't need authentication. It just needs to be downloaded in a folder e.g. named "downloads" So on the server-side. Lateron the script should automatically run via Cronjob :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The simplest scenario

You can download the report with `file_get_contents`:

```
$report = file_get_contents('http://www1.intranet.com/reportingtool.asp?...');
```

And save it locally (on the machine where PHP runs) with `file_put_contents`:

```
file_put_contents('/some/path/report.xls', $report);
```

#### More options

- If downloading requires control over the HTTP request (e.g. because you need to use cookies or HTTP authentication) then it has to be done through [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) which enables full customization of the request.
- If the report is large in size then it could be directly streamed to the destination instead of doing read/store/write in three steps (for example, using `fopen`/`fread`/`fwrite`).

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt: Sure thing, I missed it initially. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This may not work depending on your security settings, but it's a simple example:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('http://www1.intranet.com/reportingtool.asp?settings=var&export=ok');
file_put_contents('/path/to/your/location/report.xls', $file);
```

See [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) and [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).